# how to find the subarrays of the given array that matches the checkvalue?

Tags: java, arrays

find the subarrays that matches the given sum input under conditions

only one loop is allowed
cant repeat the same index for sum
no inbuild methods allowed

my Output:

```
int arr[] = { 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, 8, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1 };
int checkval = 3;
```

results:
the subarrays are:

```
index 0 to 1
index 3 
index 3
index 3 to 3
index 8 to 10
index 9 to 11
```

Subarray with most elements is 3

Kindly help me to avoid duplicate printing of single index values
also find solution to not to use the same index for next sum,

incorrect

```
index 8 to 10
index 9 to 11
```

correct

```
index 8 to 10
**next index should start with 11 not 9**
index 9 to 11


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[] = { 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, 8, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1 };
        int sum = 0;
        int indexval = 0;
        int checkval = 4;
        int i = 0;

        int len[] = new int[10];
        int l = 0;
        int lm = 0;

        System.out.println("the subarrays are: ");

        while (indexval <= arr.length) {
            int temp=i;

            if (i < arr.length)
                sum += arr[i];
            else
                break;

            if (sum <= checkval) {
                if (sum == checkval) {
                    System.out.println("index " + indexval + " to " + i);
                    len[l++] = i - indexval + 1;
                    lm = (i - indexval + 1) > len[l] ? (i - indexval + 1) : len[l];
                    i = indexval;
                    indexval += 1;
                    sum = 0;
                }
            }



            else if (arr[temp] == checkval) {
                System.out.println("index " + i);
                i = indexval;
                indexval += 1;
                sum = 0;
            }

            else if (sum > checkval) {
                i = indexval;
                indexval += 1;
                sum = 0;
            }

            i += 1;
        }
        
        System.out.println("Subarray with most elements is " + lm);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what actually is the end goal: display the *start/end* indices of each subarray or find the maximum subarray's length (that's how I interpreted the phrase *"Subarray with most elements is 3"*) ? If you need only to *display indices*, why mention *"most elements"*, but it you actually need the later - then why you're not even displaying this number?

Comment: Also clarify the requirements: **1.** What means *"can't repeat the same index"* - you need to discard some subarrays, describe how? **2.** *"only one loop is allowed"* - that means literally a **single loop** in the code, or only loop are allowed to be used and no built-in functionality.

Comment: That said, problem description is pretty vague, if you have original description in English - than just copy-past it into the question. Please edit [*your question*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73632634/edit).